# How to activate Shopware 6 Address form AdditionalField1?

Tags: shopware6

In Shopware 6, I would like to activate AdditionalField1 for the address form
how can I do this from the Admin area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-en/settings/login-registration

Within the Settings menu you will find the menu item Login / Registration.

Check **Show additional address line 1**